# Error switching activity

Tags: android

I am having an error when trying to switch from one activity(`com.intelligent.stocktrader.MyAccount`) to another(`com.intelligent.stocktrader.SharePerformanceDetails`).What am I doing wrong?
My code has no error.

Below is the log cat content:

> E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(787):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.intelligent.stocktrader/com.intelligent.stocktrader.SharePerformanceDetails}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name = org.achartengine.chart.LineChart)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(787):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(787):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)

The MyAccount activity onCreate where am switching activities

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_performance);
    //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //stock_name = extras.getString("stock");
    //new PerformanceDetails().execute();   
    LineGraph line=new LineGraph();
    Intent intent=line.getIntent(getApplicationContext());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The LineGraph class

```
public Intent getIntent(Context context){

    -----------
            -----------
    return intent;
}
```

The LineGraph class has a method that will return an intent.Tha is where the error is propagating from

Comment: post your code, there is something with the object that you put in your intent

Comment: is your activity `shareperformancedetails` registered in your manifest?

Comment: probably indicates that your class is not serializable. org.achartengine.chart.LineChart

Comment: Yes Karan the manifest is up to date.

Comment: please post your manifest also

Answer (score 1):

That's because you Intent contain LineChart, which can't be serialized. You shound make LineChart implements from java.io.Serializable.

Comment: Jared,how do i do that?

Comment: public class LineChart implements Serializable. and make its' nested complex types all implements Serializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code on onclick() it willl work-

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreen.class);
StartActivity(i);
```

To run our application you should enter your new activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. Add new Activity between  tags:

```
<activity android:name=".NewActivityClassName"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_performance);
//Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//stock_name = extras.getString("stock");
//new PerformanceDetails().execute();   
LineGraph line=new LineGraph();
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SharePerformanceDetails.class); // EDITED
startActivity(intent);
```

}

Comment: You probably want to transfer LineGraph to another activity, right?

Comment: Dino,yes.Actually am calling the LineGraph class which has a class that will return an intent to the SharePerformanceDetails class.

Comment: @mungaihkamau I belive you are certain that it works. Not taking in consideration other answers, you should make sure you properly return Intent.

Comment: Its working.From another test application its working ok.But when i try to implement the same on my project,the issues crop up.